# Calculate the partial derivatives of $\sin(x^2+y^2) $ with the limit definition of the partial derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here's what I have so far:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}|_{(a,b)} = \lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin(a^2 + b^2 + 2tb + t^2) - \sin(a^2 + b^2)}{t} = \lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{\sin(a^2 + b^2)[\cos(2tb + t^2) - 1] + \cos(a^2 + b^2)\sin(2tb + t^2)}{t}$$
I can see that side left of the plus sign might go to $0$, and the side on the right would probably go to $\cos(a^2+b^2)$, but I'm missing a $2a$ multiplying my solution!

Answer (score 1):

By definition

$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{\partial f}}
{{\partial x}}\left( {x_0 ,y_0 } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{f\left( {x_0  + h,y_0 } \right) - f\left( {x_0 ,y_0 } \right)}}
{h} \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\sin (a^2  + 2ah + h^2  + b^2 ) - \sin (a^2  + b^2 )}}
{h} =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\cos \left( {\frac{{2a^2  + 2ah + h^2  + 2b^2 }}
{2}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{{2ah + h^2 }}
{2}} \right)}}
{h} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
where we used
$$
\sin p - \sin q = 2\cos \left( {\frac{{p + q}}
{2}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{{p - q}}
{2}} \right)
$$
Now
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \cos \left( {\frac{{2a^2  + 2ah + h^2  + 2b^2 }}
{2}} \right) = \cos \left( {a^2  + b^2 } \right)
$$
by continuity of $\cos(t)$. On the other side
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{{2ah + h^2 }}
{2}} \right)}}
{h} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{2ah + h^2 }}
{{2h}} = 2a
$$
since $\sin t \sim t$ as $t \to 0$. Therefore we have that
$$
\frac{{\partial f}}
{{\partial x}}\left. {\sin (x^2  + y^2 )} \right|_{\left( {a,b} \right)}  = 2a\cos \left( {a^2  + b^2 } \right)
$$
You can calculate the other partial derivative in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Just evaluate it as a derivative of a function of $t$.
$$\frac{d}{dt} \sin(a^2 + (b+t)^2)|_{t=0} = 2b\cos(a^2 + b^2)$$